# What is the difference between a reflexive relation and an identitive relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

Given a set $X$ and a relation $R$ over $X$, we say that $R$ is reflexive if 
\begin{equation}
xRx\ \forall\ x\in X.
\end{equation}
What does 'identitive' mean? Is it the same as antisymmetry?

Seen in Struwe's book *Variational Methods: Applications to nonlinear PDE's and Hamiltonian systems, 4th ed.*, p.52:

> [image]

Comment: *Identitive* is not an English word, so it doesn’t mean anything. Are you translating a term from another language?

Comment: No I am not, I got the term from Struwe's Variational Methods book pg 52. I have a feeling he may mean antisymmetry.

Comment: Yeah I'm sure it's antisymmetry because he's got the following symbols describing 'identitive'\begin{equation} xRy\land yRx\Leftrightarrow x=y\end{equation} which I guess one is expected to to read as\begin{equation} (xRy)\land (yRx)\Leftrightarrow x=y\end{equation} which would be the antisymmetry property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is correct: Google Books gave me a look at [p. $52$ of Struwe, *Variational Methods*](http://books.google.com/books?id=8Ff2M9jBdJAC&q=identitive#v=snippet&q=identitive&f=false), and it’s very clear that he’s using the term *identitive* to mean *antisymmetric*.

Comment: Link: http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8Ff2M9jBdJAC&q=identitive#v=snippet&q=identitive&f=false